# Laravel 5.1 Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1 PHP framework. When I try to update my record, I get the error:

> "ErrorException in AdminController.php line 108: Creating default
>   object from empty value".

I have searched in google but I can't find any results to solve my problem.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/admin/no', 'AdminController@index');
Route::get('/admin/product/destroy/{id}', 'AdminController@destroy');
Route::get('/admin/new', 'AdminController@newProduct');
Route::post('/admin/product/save', 'AdminController@add');
Route::get('/admin/{id}/edit', 'AdminController@edit');
Route::patch('/admin/product/update/{id}', 'AdminController@update')
```

**AdminController**

```
 public function edit($id)
    {

        $product = Product::find($id);
        return view('admin.edit', compact('product'));

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product->id = Request::input('id');
        $product->name = Request::input('name');
        $product->description = Request::input('description');
        $product->price = Request::input('price');
        $product->imageurl = Request::input('imageurl');


        $product->save();
        //return redirect('/admin/nο');

    }
    enter code here
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">Edit Product</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" >
            <form action="/admin/product/update/{id}" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH"> <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that `$product = Product::find($id);` returns `NULL`. Add the check:

```
if(!is_null($product) {
   //redirect or show an error message    
}
```

Though this is your update method, so probably you're having an error while building the url for this method. It might be a wrong id you're passing to this route.

Your form `action` has an error:

```
<form action="/admin/product/update/{id}" method="POST">
```

Notice the curly braces, Blade's syntax is `{{ expression }}`, not just `{}`. So `id` is never passed to the `product.update` route. Just change it to:

```
<form action="/admin/product/update/{{$id}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: in edit.blade.php, shouldn't it be `{{$id}}` you forgot the `$`

Comment: I make  changes to form action but nothing, I get new error  NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Comment: @KristinK Just add this to your form: `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">`.

Answer (score 1):

check if the product exists then do the update
The form will look like this

> ```
> <form action="/admin/product/update/{{$id}}" method="POST">
> ```

**$ sign was missing** :)

Answer (score 1):

For update entity in laravel uses **PUT** method not **POST**. update form method and try.

```
<form action="/admin/product/update/{id}">

<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

Comment: There's no `method="PUT"` in HTML forms. Only `GET` and `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.php file maybe mistake your controller name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for similar issues for others..

Instead of `$product = Product::find($id);` use `$product = Product::where('some_other_id', $id);`.  I am saying this because you might be giving reference to some_other_id like a foreign key instead of primary key.